# How to create a COM DLL (class library)?

Tags: c++, delphi, visual-studio-2008, com, vb6

I have an existing COM DLL (class library), originally written in VB6 and source code now lost.

I need to very quickly rewrite to make a minor tweak it and don't have access to VB6. I understand that C++ Express 2008 will let me create the DLL, but I get bogged down ATL and the like.

Is there a really simple step by step guide to creating a COM DLL?

As an alternative to C++ Express 2008 I can also use Delphi 7.

or VC++ 2005 or VB 2005

Btw, I cannot use .NET, is must be a COM DLL. I really don't care how I created it - wither with Delphi, which I have bought, or a MS Studio Express (either C++ or VB)

Comment: sourcecode lost + minor tweak = very quickly rewrite  <-- something is wrong here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View these links they may be helpful to you.

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/23185

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=130494

http://delphi.about.com/od/comoleactivex/a/comdelphi.htm